# How to build and deploy windows application coded in .net using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, msdeploy

I am trying to learn how can I build and deploy windows application coded in .net using Azure DevOps. I am learning phase of DevOps. Don't have much idea. Any links would be great full for building and deploying windows application. I have gone through webapps, But I want to know for windows

Comment: In general, SO is not used for suggesting tutorials, rather it is best used to help solve particular coding problems you are having. Is there a certain challenge you are facing?

Comment: Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/deploy-azure/?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

1. The build process for windows app is simple. You just create a new build definition and select the template ".Net Desktop" then after build you may find the result on Artifact option. ([Create a build pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started-designer?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-nav#create-a-build-pipeline))

Select Template

[image: Select Template]

Find Result

[image: Find Result]

2. The deploy process depends from the type of your app (just folder with exe and dlls, or you use installer to deploy). So you may add the step to copy your build result to stage or run an installer in quiet mode. ([Create a release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started-designer?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-nav#create-a-release-pipeline)) But before it you have to configure your deploy agents to some stages ([Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops)). More information: [Why use Azure Pipelines for releases?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/what-is-release-management?view=azure-devops)

Comment: There actually ISN'T an option for .NET Desktop. This is what I see when trying to create a pipeline for one of my .NET 4.7.2 WinForms applications https://ibb.co/51Gpycx

Comment: @StephenYork, you`ve published the screenshot from the release pipeline. My screenshot from the build pipeline. The release pipeline does not contain the ".NET Desktop" template. I think, you have to start with empty job and create create your own steps. As example: [Deploy to a Windows Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops)

Comment: https://ibb.co/NYsNkJX Does the ".NET Core" cover .NET Framework as well? What's in your screenshot doesn't appear. On another note do you HAVE to have  VM and deploy to it? What I'm hoping for is a link to a remote folder or download link to just download the build to my local desktop. With on premises TFS there's an artifacts folder where I can navigate to the build folder. Is something along those lines possible with Azure Devops? I just want my product build and not run it on a costly Azure VM.

Comment: @StephenYork, your new screen from tasks of build or release pipeline. To get the ".Net Desktop", you have to select this path: Pipelines->New pipeline->Use the classic editor. By default you will have a download link to build results.

Comment: Thanks so much @shamrai-aleksander This whole classic view thing get tedious. Will there be a point where working in the new UI will support everything from the old? I would have thought the Classic Desktop would have been a fairly key item to support. At any rate I've been able to build and download a zip of the drop folder. You're a legend, thanks again